# How to return value in function to widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need help im new to flutter. I wanna get the return value String from my function and get it in my Text Widget. Thats not my real code, but i want it to works like that. And also every time i pressed the button, the String value also changes on the Text Widget. Thanks

```
String textReturn(String value){
  String text = "value";
  return text.toString();
}


class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SamplePageState createState() => _SamplePageState();
}

class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                textReturn("This is the value");
                }, 
              child: Text("Button")
              ),
              Text(
                textReturn
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `setState(() {someStringVariable = textReturn("This is the value");});` and `Text(someStringVariable)` but actually you dont need `textReturn` - just use `setState(() {someStringVariable = "This is the value";});` or `setState(() => someStringVariable = "This is the value");`

Comment: @pskink I think it should be the answer

Comment: @epsilon so write it as a self answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with `state` and you will no longer need the return value of your function, as setting a state causes UI to re-render and reflects changes to the values in the screen. Solution as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
 SamplePage();

@override
  _SamplePageState createState() => _SamplePageState();
}

class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
String _sampleString;

void textReturn(String value) {
  String text = "value";

  setState(() {
   _sampleString = text;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Center(
   child: Container(
     child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         FlatButton(
           onPressed: () {
             textReturn("This is the value");
           },
           child: Text("Button"),
         ),
         Text(this._sampleString)
       ],
     ),
    ),
   );
  }
 }
```